# Save a Function with JLD2

Tags: julia

I want to save a function in a `JLD2` file. Is this even possible and if so how?

```
using JLD2

a = [1,2,3]

function foo(x, y)
    x .> y
end

foo(x) = foo(x, a)

save_object("stored.jld2", foo)
```

So, I guess my point here is actually two things

- I want to save the function.
- I want it to have the method `foo(x)` available, i.e. if the `jld2` file is opened somewhere else it has the method `foo(x)` with `a = [1,2,3]`.

When someone builds a machine learning model and saves it, it must work something like this, right?

Really hope it's understandable what I mean here. If not please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with JLD2. Seems like there's an unresolved case for loading functions: https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl/issues/36

Comment: Hm, that's bad to hear. But how would I do this then? Save the definition of the function in a file and then save object `a` in a `JLD2` object. It's really hard to believe, I am the first person coming across this problem.

Comment: If you're using MLJ you can save the models with their method: https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/MLJ.jl/dev/mlj_cheatsheet/#Saving-and-retrieving-machines
Other ml libraries implement model saving and loading too. IF you're looking for a more general solution, you might want to check out ONNX.jl(https://github.com/FluxML/ONNX.jl/blob/b7c3d0b48036947257e439c31e00430b0a94690a/README.md)  https://onnx.ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some more research and some thinking, I come to the conclusion (happy to be proven wrong...) that this is not possible and/or not sensible. The comments in the question suggest using machine learning packages to save models and I think this approach explains the underlying point...

You can store data in `jld2` files and but you can not store functions in `jld2` files. What I tried here is not going to work because

```
foo(x) = foo(x, a)
```

accesses object `a` in the global environment - it does not magically store the data of `a` within the function. Furthermore, functions cannot be saved with `JLD2` - who know's, the latter one is maybe gonna change in the future.

---

Great, but what's the **solution** now??

What you can instead do is store the data...

```
using JLD2

a = [1,2,3]

save("bar.jld2", Dict("a" => a))
```

...and make the function available through a module or a script you `include()`.

```
include("module_with_foo_function.jl") 
using module_with_foo_function
using JLD2

my_dict = load("bar.jld2")
a = my_dict["a"]

foo(x) = foo(x, a)
```

And if you think about it, this is exactly what packages like `MLJ` are doing as well. There you store an object that contains the information, but the functionality comes from the package, not from your stored object.

Not sure anyone ever has a similar problem, but if so I hope these thoughts help.

Comment: This still doesn't work as JLD2 can't reconstruct your function `foo`: ERROR: MethodError: objects of type JLD2.ReconstructedTypes.var"##Main.#foo#291" are not callable. Tried this on 1.7. How about storing the function definition in a package and loading the vector `a` via JLD2?

Comment: OK, when testing it, I was probably mixing up, what code I already ran. I'll change the answer.